# gem install pg only works as sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ubuntu

I have read a lot on this topic, but seems like nobody has had the exact problem I am having.

I am trying to install Postgres support for Rails 3 on Ubuntu. If I run:

```
sudo gem install pg
```

everything works fine.

However, I am using GemFile and trying to deploy my application to Heroku, so doing:

```
bundle install
```

As part of the bundle install it fails when doing gem install pg with the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.9/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
```

Any ideas why this is happening. Surely it would also fail to install as sudo if I do not have the correct libraries installed. Is this some kind of permissions problem?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Olli

Comment: Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq) seems to be an error - is libpq installed on the heroku system?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to install libpq. Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

And btw, this may be a helpful hint for you. I usually setup my development environment using this chain (this is valid for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl zlib1g \

zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \

autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion ncurses-term \

exuberant-ctags libnotify-bin curl autoconf make automake ssh git-core git-doc imagemagick libpq-dev vim \

libreadline5 libmysqlclient-dev imagemagick libmagick+5 \

libmagick++-dev libmagickwand4 libmagickcore4 libmagickcore4-extra libmagickcore-dev \

libmagickwand-dev \

tmux libcurl4-openssl-dev \

libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 postgresql-contrib mysql-server memcached \

gimp chromium-browser chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra chromium-browser-inspector \

bind9 terminator libqt4-dev xvfb  gitk  postgresql pgadmin3  rar unrar\

ubuntu-restricted-extras vlc compizconfig-settings-manager gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried to install all these libraries, but still the same problem. Surely, if it is a missing library it would not install as sudo either? Could this be some kind of permissions problem?